# Why rgba color with alpha value makes my div transparent

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to set a background color for a different popup variant, but when I set a background value to something that has alpha value in it, but makes it transparent

the following css code

```
--color: 255, 144, 106, 0.18;

background: var(rgb(--color))
```

[screenshot with the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITryf.png)

Is there's a way for me to retain the color without making the div non transparent?

Note: I can't change the color token

tried changing the opacity of the parent or even setting a background on it, but no result

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding. Right now changing the color makes it transparent which you don't want. But you also want to retain the color without making the div non transparent?

Comment: So you can't use `#ffebe5` instead?

Comment: or `rgb(255, 235, 229)`

Comment: If you can't really change it (seems odd) the only option you really would have is to add another element behind it that is white.

Comment: @imvain2 I want to retain the color which was acheived by appying the alpha value, but I don't want it to affect the div where it's applied. I would like it to be non pransparent since I didn't set opacity explicitly

Comment: @epascarello I can't change the color value since it a design system token, but I need to apply the color somehow. Wondering if there's something I'm missing before going to discuss it with the design team

Comment: You are setting transparent, that is how the RGBA works. The two color codes above is the same basic color. So either they need to change their colors or you will have to do a hack of setting a solid white background behind the div which is possible, but does not make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

I really advise you to update the way you handle the colors. If you don't want transparency, don't set it.

In this particular case, you can hack it by using multiple layers where the bottom one is black or white depending on your need:

```css
.box {
 --color: 255, 144, 106, 0.18;
  
 background: 
   linear-gradient(rgb(var(--color)) 0 0)
   #fff;
   
 height: 200px;
}


body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,blue, red);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The alpha value changes the opacity of the color. There is not much you can do about it except changing the alpha value itself. If your div is completely transparent, you could try to add `opacity: 1;` to the styling.

Edit: I just saw the example which makes my answer kind of invalid. If you can't change the color variable, your only option is either to live with it or try to overwrite the color with a different opacity by creating a new variable.

Answer (score -1):

I see that you tagged this with javascript.

One hack that isn't as pretty as actually changing the code is using javascript to change it.

Its not perfect and might flicker on load etc.. But your system has put you in a difficult place without having access to change certain things.

```js
const div = document.querySelector("#div");
div.style.background = "#ffebe5";
```

```css
#div {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgb(255, 144, 106, 1);
}

body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: At that rate they should just change the CSS....

Comment: @epascarello I don't disagree that there are better options. OP just made it seem like it was a big deal to get the proper changes made.

Answer (score -1):

The correct syntax for RGBA values in CSS custom properties is as follows:

```
--color: rgba(255, 144, 106, 0.18);
```

Notice that I've used rgba() instead of rgb(), and this should correctly set the background color with the specified alpha (opacity) value. Using the rgba() function explicitly states that you are defining a color with an alpha channel, which should prevent the background from being fully transparent.

Here's the corrected CSS code:

```
--color: rgba(255, 144, 106, 0.18);

background: var(--color);
```